# How to print GPS location to stdout (Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04)?

Tags: gps, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04, nmea, gpsd

I'm a complete newbie with GPS devices on Linux.

I have a `GlobalSat G-STAR IV` USB device and I would just like to get the GPS location (lat, long) printed to stdout. How can I achieve that? I'm reading about `gpsd`, but not sure how to get the actual location. The documentation seems old.

Any common tools etc for this?

It seems that with

```
$ sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 4800
$ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I can read some NMEA(?) data from the device:

```
$GPGGA,113935.199,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*5B

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

$GPRMC,113935.199,V,,,,,,,100918,,,N*41

$GPGGA,113936.186,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*56

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

$GPRMC,113936.186,V,,,,,,,100918,,,N*4C

$GPGGA,113937.185,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*54

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E

$GPRMC,113937.185,V,,,,,,,100918,,,N*4E

$GPGGA,113938.200,,,,,0,00,,,M,0.0,M,,0000*55

$GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,*1E
```

I still don't see `$GPGLL` that should contain the location..?

Edit: I also get this:

```
$ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -N
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
```

I have killed all `gpsd` instances and deleted the socket, but still getting that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to make this device work were:

```
# Switch the device to NMEA mode
sudo gpsctl -f -n /dev/ttyUSB0

# Set baudrate to 4800
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 4800

# Start gpsd 
gpsd -S 4000 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Now create a TCP/IP socket connection to `localhost:4000` and say `?WATCH={"enable":true,"json":true};` or use `libgps` etc:

http://www.catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html

Comment: `joaquin@hamradio:~$ sudo gpsctl -f -n /dev/ttyUSB0`  
`gpsctl:ERROR: SER: /dev/ttyUSB0 already opened by another process`  
`gpsctl:ERROR: initial GPS device /dev/ttyUSB0 open failed`

Comment: sorry for the fragmented comment. Just to clarify : Same GPS, got data with `sudo stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 4800`, but `sudo gpsctl...` fails as shown above

Comment: Check if you have `gpsd` already running on that device..?

Comment: It was stopped. I ran `sudo killall gpsd`. BTW, This is Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Made if run after two days fighting. Thanks for help. Just a) start Ubuntu b) connect gps c) run indicated steps in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it was horror to figure out. The good thing is that the setup works very reliably once you have managed to get it running in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The output you posted from `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` is what you would expect for a GPS module, which does not (yet) have a fix, i.e. it does not have enough information to calculate its current position (+other information).

The only information provided by the messages is the current time of day, 11h39m35s, etc. Out of the messages you receive from your GPS module, not only the `$GPGLL` message can tell you about your location, but also the `$GPGGA` and `$GPRMC` messages that you do receive. If your module had a fix, you would not see several commas in a row but actual values in between.
More details about the format of the different messages can be found in this [overview](http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/).

**What is the likely root cause for the missing GPS fix (assuming your hardware + antenna are fine)?**

- You have just started using this module fresh from the factory and it needs some time to get ahold of its coordinates. The [time to first fix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_fix) for such a brand new device can be up to 15 minutes.
- The GPS signal strength is not strong enough at the location of your module.

**Therefore my advice:**

- Make sure that at your location, the GPS signal from the satellites is strong enough. Ideally by moving outdoors.
- When your module has never had a fix before, give your module some time. Wait for up to 20 minutes.

**GPSD:**

GPSD, if installed, is normally started automatically, when you plug in a GPS module. You can check the current status with

```
systemctl status gpsd.service
systemctl status gpsd.socket
```

If active, the `gpsd` deamon reads out the GPS-data coming via the serial interface and provides it to other applications via a socket on a specific port (default: port 2947). In that case the serial port is not accessible anymore by serial monitors.